# Element at "//div[contains(@class,"connexion-content")]//select" is not clickable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, python-behave

I'm trying to run some tests automation on a web application (Angular2, https and websocket) with: gherkin,behave 1.2.6, selenium 3.141.0, firefox and python 3.9.4, geckodriver 0.29.1, allure-behave 2.8.40.

Configuration :
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"

Locator :
select = (By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"connexion-content")]//select')

Error :
Assertion Failed: Item "profilselect.select" not found in current page, cannot set value on it
Captured logging:WARNING:root:[ACTION] waitForClickable => Element at "//div[contains(@class,"connexion-content")]//select" is not clickable.

Html option I want to select : Please note that « value » can’t be used because I’m only interest by the text between the « option » tag, is only if the given text correspond to a specific value that it is selected
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your element itself is of type select why don't you use Selenium Select class where your can interact directly with it by text or index.

Comment: Please, could you show me how to do it ? a sample code...

Comment: @Bizi This should help you https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

Since u have not shown your code, I can only help with pseudocode:

```
we_sel = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'form-1-1'))

# The above statement is equivalent to below statement.

# If you are not familiar with WebDriver Waits then uncomment the below statement and comment the above statement.

# we_sel = driver.find_element_by_id('form-1-1')

sel = Select(we_sel)
sel.select_by_visible_text('replace withoption text u want to select')
```

References (Webdriver API Docs):

1. For `Select` class:
   https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select
2. For `WebDriverWait` class:
   https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait
3. For `expected_conditions` module:
   https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions